# Macs on Active Directory. Password policies not being enforced

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx

Okay. Fundamentally, I've just started a new job where all of their IT support is outsourced. I've come in and realised password policies just aren't being enforced on any OS X machine in the building as they're connected to a windows active directory. I've tried to contact the outsourced support and asked them to look into ways to get around this but the response is pretty much 'yeah it doesn't work'. Which is frustrating!

I know that there are 'teething' problems to say the least when trying to enforce password policies etc from windows active directory to Macs that have joined said directory. Looking online third party extensions like ADmitMac were suggested but this is now being discontinued. The only thing that I can think of to save myself this headache is to buy a Mac mini. Set up an OS X server and connect all the Macs to it myself (20 max) and set policies that way.

Now I may be missing something blindingly obvious about how to get a Mac to play nice with Active directory policies. So please shout at me if I am! but any advice on how best to achieve this I'd be hugely grateful!

Comment: Whatever you do, please make sure to get signoff from your management, and work with the outsource team.

Comment: Of course! I wouldn't just jump in and do something. I'd love to present them with a solution rather than a problem though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X / macOS in theory *should* actually play pretty well with AD these days, as Apple has pretty much abandoned Open Directory. While the gold standard for Apple management is, indeed, [jamf](https://jamf.com), there is extensive support built in. Here's the page on [Domain Password Policy](https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/guide/directory-utility/ior9dfab7fbd/5.0/mac/10.14.2). Have you looked over the Directory Utility docs? I.e.,

- [Integrate Active Directory](https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/guide/directory-utility/diru39a25fa2/5.0/mac/10.14.2)
- [Configuring Domain Policy](https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/guide/directory-utility/diru11f4f748/5.0/mac/10.14.2)
- [Setting up Mobile Accounts](https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/guide/directory-utility/diruc37c9dad/5.0/mac/10.14.2)

If so, does everything seem to look as it should? Otherwise, are you specifically saying that everything is working fine *except* password policies? Like, AD users are allowed to keep passwords for longer than they should?

Comment: Thanks for the response Geoff. I know the active directory policies work fine for all other machines that aren't Macs (Windows laptops). The main issue I'm coming across is Mac users never have to reset their passwords and trying to set a group auto-lock policy and screensaver just aren't working.

Comment: It I had to guess (unfortunately I don't have a present similar setup to play with it), it sounds like either the machine or the local user accounts aren't properly bound. `dsconfigad [-show]` is probably the easiest way to check this. The man page is pretty descriptive of its usage. There **are** `-localpassword` and `-password`  options that could be set, overriding AD policies. Couple other things: they all should be running 10.12 or later, and if you have multiple AD servers/domains, make sure the one that enforces these policies are taking precedence. I'd toss any fallbacks.

Comment: You might also try asking over at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

And if it still persists, I would definitely contact the folks at jamf before going for a Mac mini server, and see if they have a hosted solution that would work in your budget. Apple's "Server" software is a shadow of what it once was, everything is done via MDM these days.

Comment: Thanks for all of the support Geoff! Yeah, they seem to have somewhat left Open directory in the past and no longer really offer any support.

Comment: You bet! To be clear though: to say Apple has "left Open Directory in the past" is not 100% correct. The core of Open Directory is still actually how Apple products manage directory services locally (since 10.5). (Recall that OD is really just fancy OpenLDAP.) What *has* been left in the past is **hosting an Open Directory _master (domain)_**. But the /Local/Default domain, `dscl .`, etc., are still critical OS components. In fact, the AD support is technically an OD plug-in. So there are still occasions where `odutil` and tools like that are useful.